# Кто работал с библиотекой DevIL? что такое имена изображений?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, devil

Пытаюсь научиться пользоваться этой библиотекой..
Что такое имена изображений?
К примеру в документации есть такая функция
ILvoid ilGenImages(ILsizei Num, ILuint *Images);
Написано что она принимает массив ILUINT для получения сгенерированных имен изображений.
Я как понял эти имена не несут информацию о цветах и пикселях?

Comment: http://openil.sourceforge.net/tuts/tut_4/index.htm Еще могу пояснить, что такой кривой интерфейс сильно смахивает но OpenGL.

Comment: Здравствуйте, все ровно немного не догоняю... 
К примеру есть функция:
`ILboolean ilLoadImage(const char *FileName);`
в описании написано мол : - это основная функция загрузки дьявола. Все, что вам нужно сделать, это передать ilLoadImage имя файла изображения, которое вы хотите загрузить. Об остальном позаботится ilLoadImage.
Значит я могу использовать сразу эту функцию? ну она же обо всем позобатится! или она просто так работать не будет? как я понял из ссылки что вы кинули нужно создавать имена изображений? 

 `

Comment: Просто не пойму эти имена изображений обязательные функции? просто они идут первые по документации, я так понял должна быть определенная последовательность?

Comment: Имена изображений (которые ILuint) - это по факту примитивные дескрипторы, посредством которых осуществляется доступ к объектам-изображениям. Именами она видимо называются потому, что дебильные интерфейс и терминология были позаимствованы из OpenGL. Функции, не принимающие дескрипторы явно, типа `ilLoadImage`, неявно работают с *текущим* объектом, который задается вызовом `ilBindImage`. Ну и перед этим его естественно нужно создать, а после - удалить.

Comment: Так.... сперва идет  ilGenImages. потом ilBindImage. а потом я открываю картинку с помощью ilLoadImage? или все таки может попробовать сразу ilLoadImage? или она так не работает?

Comment: аа или сперва создаем ilGenImages, потом открывает картинку ilLoadImage, потом привязываем  ilBindImage? потом ес ли нужно удаляем? так?

Comment: Я же написал: Функции, не принимающие дескрипторы явно, типа ilLoadImage, неявно работают с *текущим* объектом, который задается вызовом ilBindImage.

Comment: а как после открытия изображения функцией 'ilLoadImage', получить данные о ширине и высоте? В документации есть функция 'ILboolean ilTexImage( ILuint Width, ILuint Height, ILuint Depth, ILubyte Bpp, ILenum Format, ILenum Type, ILvoid *Data);' с помощью ее? или как?